# Angular focus and input in modal on top of another modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, focus

Hi I have a directive that focuses inputs modals. The focus works just great when its a single modal. In one instance though I have a modal and then clicking a button on this modal fires another modal on top. The focus then does not work.

Any ideas?

This is my code:

```
.directive('auto-focus', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, el) {
      var whiteList = ['input', 'a', 'textarea', 'div']
        , tagToFocus = el[0].tagName.toLowerCase()
        , allow = whiteList.indexOf(tagToFocus) > -1;

      if (!allow) {
        throw new Error(`Autofocus is not allowed on ` + tagToFocus);
     }

    $timeout(() => el[0].focus(), 50);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus ?

Comment: In fact I did but got no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your directive is OK, problem may be the way you open your modal.

I guess 2nd modal use already `rendered html`. Suppose you have hidden html template, somewhere in your page. If your 2nd modal use that hidden html template then `focus` wouldn't work ! You can check this by `console.log` your element.

If your 2nd modal use any part of your 1st modal html it wouldn't work either !

So this will work only for fresh injected html or you have to re-run your directive after modal open.

Check this [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/IiYqOVSRRot3YNoz2ua0?p=preview) for further clarification.

Comment: That was exactly it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I assume that what happens it the directive `auto-focus` is in both popups. That means that both directives are competing for focus and the one executed later  wins. That's my guess.

So I would try to delay the `focus()` of the later popup.

You can add parametrize your `auto-focus` directive with optional `timeout` parameter. If not provided, it would default to that 50ms. If provided, than the custom value would be used.

Then html in your 2nd popup would look this:

```
<div> ....
 <input auto-focus timeout="250"/>
</div>
```

Update your directive like this

```
//just a draft :)
....
restrict: 'A',
scope: {
 timeout: '=' //This will create new isolate scope
}
link: function(scope, el) {
 if (scope.timeout == undefined) {
  //set default value
  scope.timeout = 50;
 }
 else {
  scope.timeout = parseInt(scope.timeout, 10);
....

 }
```

Comment: Thank you I will give this a go and let you know